# How to run an Excel macro every Monday using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: vba, excel, exe, windows-task-scheduler

I created a macro that refreshes the data automatically and then it saves the file to a particular folder. I would like to set up a scheduled job that automatically runs my macro every Monday morning.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you google this first? It seems like there are a lot of results that cover how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the workbook that runs your Macro make sure it is called in the `ThisWorkbook` Module `Workbook_Open`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call YourMacroHere
End Sub
```

Then go to `Task Scheduler` and select `Create Basic Task`

[image]

Then give your task a name

[image]

Click `Next` and define your schedule

[image]

-> Next ->

[image]

-> Next -> `Start a Program`

[image]

-> Next -> `Browse` and select your workbook

[image]

-> Next -> Confirm everything is correct and Finish

[image]

This will then, provided your computer is turned on will then open that Workbook every Monday at 9am. The `Workbook_Open()` event will then fire executing your macro. You may want to add to your code as well to shutdown the workbook after the macro has finished.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom! This was truly helpful